# I am using react-select and I want to fetch data on `onFocus` event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using react-select and I want to fetch data when the user clicks the `select`.

```
 const fetchData = () => {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res => res.data)
  }
....
      <AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        loadOptions={fetchData}
        value={selectedValue}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        getOptionValue={option => option.value}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        placeholder="Select a person"
      />
```

Here, data is fetched when the page is loaded but I want to fetch data on the `onFocus` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a function as `onFocus` to props that function will be executed on focus of the select.

```
<AsyncSelect
        // your default props
        onFocus={fetchData} // if some data is required to be sent to
        // fetchData then you can use 
        // onFocus ={()=>fetchData(yourData)}
      />
```

You can read more about it [here](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)

also you can store the data in a state and pass it to the select component if you want to update it later.

Edit:- I solved it for you this was not working because you are using async select which automatically sets the data for you. i used normal select to show you how it should be done.
Here is the link to sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-waterfall-dchfx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yeah, I read the docs but just passing `onFocus={fetchData}` doesn't work. Can you provide a working codesandbox?

Comment: Is your problem solved or should i give you sandbox

Comment: No, it's not solved. I would be happy if you provide a working sandbox.

Comment: @Bearded i have updated the answer for you please check that

Answer (score 0):

data can be fetched from using redux also [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/optimistic-orla-m930lw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)